# Python Openpyxl: Writing to sheet rows with multiple values from object

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Think I'm overlooking the answer so need a fresh pair of eyes. My script should search and get tweets, then write the tweet date, username, and tweet text on one row, separated by columns. Then write the next matching tweet to a new row and so on. Printing the returned twitter object values confirms all ok. Can print and separate the data for each tweet. However, when writing to Excel, my loop code just writes the first tweet n times, without the remaining tweets.

Code:

```
print ('TEST PRINT...')
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberOfTweets):
    print(tweet.created_at)
    print(tweet.user.screen_name)
    print(tweet.text)
    print '\n'

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberOfTweets):
    for rowNum in range(3, sheet.max_row):
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = tweet.created_at
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value = tweet.user.screen_name
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = tweet.text
    break
```

The second code block is the issue. How can I write the three above tweet values for each tweet on separate rows?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are looping with the same tweet. Try this (i could't test) :

```
rowNum = 0 # or 3 ?
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberOfTweets):
    sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value = tweet.created_at
    sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value = tweet.user.screen_name
    sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = tweet.text
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Returning to code and its coming back quicker each day.